# How can we prevent re-render of previous screen when navigating back from B screen to A in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, rerender, jetpack

Example: Home Screen Or Detail Screen

When Clicking on some Items it will move to the Detail screen when going back to the Home screen. home screen re-render. How we can prevent.

Below I'm sharing Video

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J1CCYr3WUc2YDlhzlL5Cgk1O-dr8kgZ5/view?usp=sharing

Also Sharing Code Of Lines Below

```
      @Composable
     fun AppNavigationGraph() {
       val navController: NavHostController =rememberNavController()
     NavHost(
    navController = navController, startDestination = 
     Screen.Login.route
) {
    composable(route = Screen.Login.route) {
        LoginScreen(
            onNavigateToHome = { navController.navigateToHome() },
        )
    }

    composable(route = Screen.Home.route) {
        HomeScreen(

        )
    }
}

}

    fun NavController.navigateToHome() = navigate(Screen.Home.route) {}
```

Comment: Please edit your post and include code of a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @binal can you please put the video of your problem?

Comment: @HanifShaikh Please check I also added code

Comment: @Binal If you want to navigate back, you should call navcontroller.popBackStack() . When you call navcontroller.navigate(Screen.Home.route)  you are creating a new instance of the destination (Screen.Home.route) and add it to the backstack, 

[here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/backstack#basic-behavior) is the basic of compose navigation